# "_nano_vet_and_size_of_live" Crashes Only Found in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I was using [KSCrash](https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash) to collect crash information for my app. Since the release of iOS 10, I was seeing a huge wave of crashes only in iOS 10 devices. These crashes share quite a few similarities.

1. All of them ends with Signal Abort.
2. All of them are from iOS 10 devices.
3. All of them have "**_nano_vet_and_size_of_live (in libsystem_malloc.dylib)**" in the backtrace of the crashed thread.
4. Most of them have a "Freeing Unallocated Pointer" string in one of the registers of the crashed thread. (KSCrash will try to read and save register information when crashes happen)

It appears to be a crash that could happen in a lot of places. Some backtraces have a lot of CoreText symbols in it. Others seem to be CFPropertyList related, or ImageIO related, or even sqlite related.

I suspect it's an iOS 10 bug. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm also seeing crashes in iOS 10 only from a couple different places in my app, as reported by Crashlytics. One of the crashes originates from Google Analytics, and two others from places where we are creating strings.  They all seem to be related to string creation, and fail right after a call to _nano_vet_and_size_of_live.

Answer (score 0):

Many crashes that originate from libsystem_malloc.dylib are due to system memory issues.  I've seen stacktraces with this, but no real pointer to the cause.  After grabbing a sysdaignose from one of my old iOS 10.x devices, I realized that every time this happened the device had very little free RAM.  I found that this occurred less after a fresh restart.  While not an ideal answer, this usually occurs when the system cannot allocate any additional memory due to limited RAM, or a catastrophic issue with the runtime that requires a restart or respring of the device (think when the kernel cannot open a new mach port).